# Spawning multiple threads that monitor different files in a servlet

Tags: java, multithreading, servlets, executorservice

I am trying to spawn multiple threads that monitor different log files. So basically user types in the host and path of log file to tail, then hits the montior button which will then start a thread and initiate the tailing. My problem is that I know threads are not supposed to be spawned in a servlet as it would cause tomcat to complain about resources. The other thing is I need to be able to stop tailing of the file whenever the user decides to stop monitoring button. My first approach was to have a map that takes in the thread and starts tailing of file, then whenever I hit stop monitoring file then I get thread by key then call a method stopThread which I flag a volatile attribute in and set it to false then it stops. 
Is there a way which I can do it maybe using ExecutorService and make the thread run without halting the program as I understand that Callable will wait for results to return which in my case I don't want halting. Any shed of ligh is highly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: @FaddishWorm: I don't think watching log files is covered by log4j.

Comment: Hi everyone, @ FaddishWorm, thanks for the your reply really appreciate it but Thilo is correct, log4j is not what I am looking for.